# How to build a $wpdb query

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build a query that will help me rank [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com/) search results by total_sales (in a WooCommerce shop).

SearchWP has a simple [filter](https://searchwp.com/docs/kb/have-recently-published-posts-rank-higher/) that helps injecting additional sql into the search algorithm and adding weight as desired.

The following example lets recent posts rank higher:

```
$sql .= " + ( IF( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date ) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( {$time_ago} ), {$additional_weight}, 0 ) )";
```

So I tried to do the same thing by using the total_sales column from the postmeta table to increase the weight of search results, but it doesn't work.

```
$sql .= " + {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.total_sales";
```

Obviously I wonder what the solution is. 
But I also want to know a way how to build and test such a $wpdb query successfully myself. A link to a good tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting so far. What isn't working?

Comment: With my code the search algorithm is returning no results at all.

Comment: `$sql` is an SQL statement. Can you show the entire statement you've generated including your `$sql .= " + {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.total_sales";` addition. I suspect the SQL is invalid, but it's impossible to tell without more detail

Comment: I have difficulties extracting the `$sql` from SearchWP. But I narrowed my part to`$sql .= " + ( SELECT \`meta_value\` FROM \`wp_postmeta\` WHERE \`post_id\` = wp_posts.ID AND \`meta_key\` = \'total_sales\' )";`. Unfortunately this also brings back search results that don't match my search keyword. I'll contact the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by following this SearchWP documentation. It is another filter provided by the SearchWP plugin: https://searchwp.com/docs/kb/using-custom-field-prioritize-search-results/

Simply drop both filters into functions.php and change the line

```
$my_meta_key = 'my_search_priority';
```

to

```
$my_meta_key = 'total_sales';
```

It works like a charm